# Debian Jessie python3 installation fails

Tags: debian, apt, python3

I know there are other posts here asking how to install python 3.6, but all I want is a version of python 3. The repos seem to have python 3.4, which is fine but the problem is that apt-get is not responding in a way that makes sense. When I try the command apt-get install python3 I get the response:

```
python3 is already the newest version.
```

This is despite the fact that python -V command tells me python is 2.7.9. How do I install python 3 please?

Comment: python2.7 is set as default  ,python  3 is already installed  try `python3 -V`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `python` interpreter is Python 2. If you want to run Python 3, you need to use the command `python3`.  I would expect running `python3 -V` would give you `Python 3.4.x`.

Answer (score 0):

The tow version of python is already installed on your system , to list them :

```
 update-alternatives --list python
```

sample output:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python3.5
```

To set python3 as default run:

```
update-alternatives --config python
```

Choose python 3.5